# Get list of all files (every file) in both internal and external storage with absolute path in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an app which analyses the user's storage and give information like Total Images, Videos, Audios, Archives, Executables and other files. With MediaStore i can only get the Media files files but i want a list of every single file present on the device's storage (both internal and external) with their absolute path so that i can access them.

Comment: On Android 10 and higher, you do not have access to "every single file present" on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). On all Android versions, you do not have access to "every single file present" on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare i don't necessarily mean files from other application internal data. I need all the files which are accessible to a normal user.

Comment: You are referring then to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and you do not have access to that data on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare not even without the Write and Read permission? There is a new permission ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION

Comment: "not even without the Write and Read permission?" -- correct. External storage [is greatly restricted on Android 10 and higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare But there is this new permission which is only required on Android 10 and higher - ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION

Comment: That is not related to accessing files on external storage. That has to do with getting location data from media (e.g., geotagged photos).

Comment: @CommonsWare can you check and tell if the answer to this question below will work?

Comment: It does not address the problems that I outline in this series of comments, if that is what you are asking. If you are asking "is that a Java snippet for traversing a directory tree?", then yes, that is what that code snippet does.

Comment: @CommonsWare to address that i could use MediaStore for Images, Audio and Videos but what about the documents. How can i get other files in Android 10 or Higher, or is that impossible now.

Comment: Personally, I do not recommend that you pursue developing this specific set of functionality, as you are "swimming against the current" of where Android is headed. There is no means for you to get filesystem access in Android 10 for the files that you seek. You could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` from the Storage Access Framework, then traverse that tree. However, this will be very slow, as it is not designed for the sorts of bulk operations that you would need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.....
List<File> files = getListFiles(new File("YOUR ROOT")); 
....
private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        } else {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".csv")){
                inFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return inFiles;
}
```